# How to write an image after after having resize it

Tags: php

I am trying to resize photos with a function that I get from the official website of PHP. It's a function that resize photos without losing their ratio.

```
public function ImageResize($filename, $max_width,$max_height){

    list($orig_width,$orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

    $width = $orig_width;
    $height = $orig_height;

    #c'est la photo est grande.
    if($height > $max_height){
        $width = ($max_height/$height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    #c'est la photo est larage
    if($width > $max_width){
        $height = ($max_width/$width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

    return $image_p;

}
```

This function is supposed to send me a picture, the question is: does the reduced image is automatically written to disk or I have to do more processing to make the change between the old and the new picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image will only be available in the variable $image_p until you save it. Like this:

```
imagejpeg($image_p, 'your_image_in_disk.jpg');
```